# Where Is My Home?

Tags: riddle, word, poetry

I am not from where you're from,
But you've seen my home before.
It's smaller than you're used to,
With weather you can't ignore.
In the morning you see it,
And in the evening it's there,
But if you search late at night,
You won't find it anywhere.
Like you, I love the sunrise-
To feel the warmth on my skin.
How I dread to wait two years
To enjoy it once again.
But please, don't be disheartened
When my home changes its look.
It's just going through a phase,
which I trust you'll overlook.
I'm sure you can acknowledge
its great eccentricity,
And that it's the least tilted
Of any place we can see.
Although it is quite tiny,
It's packed quite tightly, really.
And though it can be real hot,
It also gets quite chilly.
I hope you'll be attracted
by all these wonderful things,
And admire its dance, with soul,
Which is filled with such wide swings.

Disclaimer: Created 100% from my own brain over the past 72 hours. No AI was used. :)

A correct answer will explain all the lines.

Comment: @PDT I take your point but disagree to an extent - I think there will always be room for a nicely crafted riddle. Part of the art of the riddle is in its poetry, imagery, and creative presentation. While an online solving tool might get an answer, only a human reader can truly appreciate the creativity behind it, and there's still joy to be had in that :)

Comment: @PDT if anything I think it'll show the difference between a really good riddle and an ok one, the best riddles won't be solvable by AI due to twists or a trick only a human would be able to clock onto

Comment: @ yesterday well I typed the last part of a supposedly more ai proof kind of a riddle that is the affix riddles- the original Riley riddle (with triple figure upvotes) can’t call it bad and asked Poe to give me all the possibilities of the clue I think the answer was found only around 5 options down. Another top riddle recently that I answered again (although I didn’t do this foolishly), I put it through Poe and boom I got the answer. If it doesn’t give the answer immediately it can significantly increase its solvability at least. There are ways I admit to bypass ai but that would be making….

Comment: Some unconventional riddle, like where the parts are referring to some alteration through the manipulation of letters for example like in cryptic clues or we will have some rubbish obscure one but conventional riddles like these are put out of business for good imo. Just for the record regardless of whether this riddle can be easily solved or not by ai doesn’t take anything away from it or any riddle for that matter-this is an excellent riddle in my eyes!

Comment: All I am saying is that because of ai these puzzles are a lot less likely to be a highly voted hit (no matter how well crafted they are handmade so to speak) on this website because people are going to look at the puzzle and the answer and be like ‘well an ai could do that’ he probably just made chat gpt do it for him and not give it any upvotes.

Comment: @PDT If one was to create a riddle that AI could not solve, would it almost certainly be no fun for humans? As Stiv said, there's joy in figuring it out. Sure, there are those who just want to solve it by any means necessary, but where's the fun in that? They are missing the point, at least the intended point. I've never seen ChatGP or the other one you mentioned, but I will now! You've got me curious!

Comment: @jlee I just asked Poe to make a riddle about a pawn and it trumped mine and I did one for this too I would love to share it.

Comment: @PDT Actually, Poe got it wrong: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMNug.png. And I told it that that was incorrect, and its second guess was wrong too.

Comment: It was right in the second guess let me show it

Comment: First response with the title added on my puzzle today: still not convinced about the end of riddles for PSE: https://ibb.co/k5Rpxkv

Comment: @PDT For me, It guessed the moon for its second guess. On to another topic: do you enjoy riddles, PDT? Why are you asking an AI? Do you really care about these utterly worthless rep points? Because you do realize that they are utterly worthless, right? The fun is in the journey. And if you must cheat, and ask someone else, where is the fun in that? You are only cheating yourself. But please have the decency to not post this kind of thing directly on people's puzzles. People put time and energy into these things. I was shocked at some of your comments on PrimNumbahs "rainbow"-looking post.

Comment: @PDT They were just rude- flat out rude.

Comment: @jlee I apologize, I didn’t realize the things that I said could be so hurtful, for the record, I did upvote this riddle and said it was excellent. I apologize for harshly criticizing Prime Numbers puzzle too.

Comment: @PDT Thanks, it's all good, PDT. forgiven and forgotten. The whole reason I brought it up was to get it back to good. I look forward to your puzzles and answers in the future. No hard feelings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is it

> Mercury?

To go (more or less) line by line as requested:

**I am not where you're from**

> It's not Earth

**Though you've seen my home before**

> Mercury is observable with the naked eye

**It's smaller than you're used to**

> The smallest planet in the solar system

**With weather you can't ignore**

> Mercury doesn't really have an atmosphere so it's hard to "ignore" solar winds or micrometeorites

**In the morning you see it**

> Mercury can be seen during morning twilight

**And in the evening it's there**

> Mercury can also be seen during evening twilight

**But if you search late at night** 
**You won't find it anywhere**

> *Very best case* for seeing Mercury is early fall or late winter on the Southern hemisphere where it sets a couple of hours after sunset, but sunset in late winter is still early enough a couple hours out from that probably doesn't count as "late at night". It being closer than Earth to the sun, we only ever see it close to the sun, with the highest "angle" to the sun (from our point of view) being between 18° to 28° (the times at which this happen fall into early fall/late winter on the Southern hemisphere).

...okay, I might have to take some of it in chunks: 
**Like you, I love the sunrise** 
**To feel the warmth on my skin** 
**How I dread to wait two years** 
**To enjoy it once again**

> A day on Mercury is two Mercury years

**But please, don't be disheartened** 
**When my home changes its look** 
**It's just going through a phase** 
**Which I trust you'll overlook**

> Mercury has "phases" like the moon

**I'm sure you can acknowledge** 
**Its great eccentricity**

> Mercury has the most eccentric orbit of all planets in the solar system

**And that it's the least tilted**

> Mercury has an axial tilt of almost zero

**Of any place we can see**

> ...which is lower than any other planet in the solar system plus the Moon in any case

**Although it is quite tiny**

> Again, smallest planet

**It's rather massive, really**

> ...but <s>smallest *planet* is still big</s> while it's smaller than some moons in the solar system it's also got a higher mass than they do.

**And although it can be real hot**

> Highest surface temperature is 427°C

**It also gets quite chilly**

> lowest surface temperature is -173°C

**I hope you'll be attracted** 
**By all these wonderful things** 
**And admire its dance, with soul**

> Might be a reach, but the *god* Mercury in Roman mythology guided souls to the underworld. Alternatively, "soul" is a (near) homophone for "Sol", as in the Sun, since that's what it orbits.

**Which is filled with such wide swings**

> Again, Mercury's orbit, maybe the eccentricity (it "swings" pretty far), the periods where it looks like it's moving in retrograde from Earth,...

Comment: All right, gave it another shot! Hope I haven't made a complete hash of explaining the visibility....

Comment: I was on the fence about whether to bring up the density, I kept thinking what if it‘s a trap because you’d specified mass. Extremely fair about the visibility though, my spatial reasoning skills are best described as hot garbage :P

Comment: good point about density. i see why you hesitated to bring that up. Just update that visibility part and i will checkmark this one. Great job.

Comment: I went ahead and changed that line that mentioned "massive", since, to your point, it is not the same as density. You can edit that into your answer if you want, or leave it as it is. either way.